# QML Map visible region

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qml

In my application, I am using `QtLocation` to display a map. Since there is only QML API to render the map, here is my QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtLocation 5.5

Item{
    anchors.fill: parent

    Plugin{
        id: osmplugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: map
        plugin: osmplugin;
        zoomLevel: (maximumZoomLevel - minimumZoomLevel)/2
        center {
            // The Qt Company in Oslo
            latitude: 59.9485
            longitude: 10.7686
        }
    }

    function bbox(){
        return map.visibleRegion;
    }
}
```

In the C++ code, I need to know the currently visible region in the map widget, QML `Map` has the property visibleRegion http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#visibleRegion-prop

But I don't understand how to get it from C++ code, since `QGeoShape` is abstract;

I tried this:

```
    QQuickItem* map = mMap->rootObject();
    QGeoRectangle rect;
    bool ok = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( map, "bbox",  Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG( QGeoRectangle, rect ) );
    if ( !ok )
        qDebug() << " Shit happens!";

    qDebug() << rect.isValid();
```

But it did not help. Please tell me how do I get visible rectangle from QML `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
QQuickItem* map = mMap->rootObject();
QVariant ret;
bool ok = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( map, "bbox",  Qt::DirectConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG( QVariant, ret ) );
if ( !ok ){
    qWarning( "Fail to call qml method" );
}
QGeoRectangle rect = qvariant_cast<QGeoRectangle>( ret );
mNorth = rect.topLeft().latitude();
mSouth = rect.bottomLeft().latitude();
mWest  = rect.topLeft().longitude();
mEast  = rect.topRight().longitude();
```