# Is there an equivalent to visibleMapRect of IOS in QT/QML?

Tags: qt, maps, qml, coordinates

In IOS, visibleMapRect returns the area currently displayed by the map view.

With Qt/QML, we are able to get individual coordinates from points on the screen like :

```
PointNW = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0))
```

Is there a method to directly get back the geoRectangle currently displayed in Qt/QML ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find it ! The answer is : visibleRegion

Doc here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#visibleRegion-prop

How to use it in C++ here : [QML Map visible region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651748/qml-map-visible-region)

Comment: note that as of Qt5.10, doing it that way is not going to work anymore.
You have to retrieve the boundingGeoRectangle from the visible region

Comment: I agree. Here is the doc : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgeoshape.html#boundingGeoRectangle